# git-svn clone a single module

Tags: git, svn

I have a repository like:

```
trunk/a/b/c
branches/V1/a/b/c
branches/V2/a/b/c
tags/T1/a/b/c
tags/T2/a/b/c
```

I'd like to work on module 'c', not checking out any other module. What is the git-svn command to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do `git svn init` with whatever options e.g.,

   ```
   $ git svn init http://svn.example.com/ -T trunk/a/b/c -t tags/T1/a/b/c \
         -b branches/V1/a/b/c
   ```
2. Edit your `.git/config` as shown below
3. Make `get svn fetch`

[`git-svn manual page`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) says that you may use in your `.git/config` to fetch all branches and tags:

```
[svn-remote "project-c"]
     url = http://server.org/svn
     fetch = trunk/a/b/c:refs/remotes/trunk
     branches = branches/*/a/b/c:refs/remotes/branches/*
     tags = tags/*/a/b/c:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Or to select only a few branches:

```
[svn-remote "project-c"]
     url = http://server.org/svn
     fetch = trunk/a/b/c:refs/remotes/trunk
     branches = branches/{V1,V2}/a/b/c:refs/remotes/branches/*
     tags = tags/{T1,T2}/a/b/c:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Comment: For me it also worked without edition the `.git/config` file, just used `git svn init http://svn.example.com/ -T trunk/a/b/c -t tags/\*/a/b/c -b branches/\*/a/b/c` and the config file was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is possible... You can check only the module in the trunk using the complete url to the folder:

```
git svn clone url/trunk/a/b/c
```

You can try using the --branches --tags parameters but i don't think that this will work

```
git svn clone --trunk=/trunk/a/b/c --branches=/branches --tags=/tags url
```